# Memory leak in FindMinValue?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry, memory

I was running some geometric optimisation code today using `FindMinValue` and for some reason at one point the memory usage goes upwards of 14GB, making the kernel quit on my little 16GB machine. I had similar code running fine yesterday before upgrading to Mathematica 13, so the issue might be a bug in the new version. I've even wrapped my optimisation function in `MemoryConstrained` but it seems to ignore that option. Any possible help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

inSquare[x_, y_, a_, b_, θ_] := 
 With[{x1 = (x - a) Cos[θ] + (y - b) Sin[θ], y1 = -(x - a) Sin[θ] + (y - b) Cos[θ]},
    -1/2 < x1 < 1/2 && -1/2 < y1 < 1/2]

overlapSquare[x_, y_, θ_] := 
 inSquare[-1/2, -1/2, x, y, θ] || inSquare[1/2, 1/2, x, y, θ] || 
 inSquare[-1/2, 1/2, x, y, θ] || inSquare[1/2, -1/2, x, y, θ] || 
 With[{cφ = Cos[θ + Pi/4]/Sqrt[2], sφ = Sin[θ + Pi/4]/Sqrt[2]}, 
  inSquare[x + cφ, y + sφ, 0, 0, 0] || inSquare[x + sφ, y - cφ, 0, 0, 0] || 
  inSquare[x - cφ, y - sφ, 0, 0, 0] || inSquare[x - sφ, y + cφ, 0, 0, 0]]

cube[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, θ_?NumberQ] := 
 Parallelepiped[{a - Cos[θ + Pi/4]/Sqrt[2], b - Sin[θ + Pi/4]/Sqrt[2], 1/2},
   {{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, {-Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]

region[w_?NumberQ, th_?NumberQ, dir_?StringQ] := Switch[dir,
  "up", Parallelepiped[{-1/2 - w, -1/2 - w, 1/2}, {{1 + 2 w, 0, 0}, {0, 1 + 2 w, 0}, {0, 0, th}}],
  "down", Parallelepiped[{-1/2 - w, -1/2 - w, -1/2}, {{1 + 2 w, 0, 0}, {0, 1 + 2 w, 0}, {0, 0, -th}}],
  "left", Parallelepiped[{-1/2, -1/2 - w, -1/2 - w}, {{-th, 0, 0}, {0, 1 + 2 w, 0}, {0, 0, 1 + 2 w}}],
  "right", Parallelepiped[{1/2, -1/2 - w, -1/2 - w}, {{th, 0, 0}, {0, 1 + 2 w, 0}, {0, 0, 1 + 2 w}}],
  "back", Parallelepiped[{-1/2 - w, -1/2, -1/2 - w}, {{1 + 2 w, 0, 0}, {0, -th, 0}, {0, 0, 1 + 2 w}}],
  "front", Parallelepiped[{-1/2 - w, 1/2, -1/2 - w}, {{1 + 2 w, 0, 0}, {0, th, 0}, {0, 0, 1 + 2 w}}]]

undefToZero[num_] := If[num === Undefined, 0, num];
overlap[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, θ_?NumberQ, w_, th_] := overlap[a, b, θ, w, th] = Total[
  undefToZero@Volume[RegionIntersection[cube[a, b, θ], region[w, th, #]], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] &
     /@ {"up", "down", "front", "back", "left", "right"}]

minArea[w_?NumberQ, th_?NumberQ] := minArea[w, th] = MemoryConstrained[
   FindMinValue[{overlap[a, b, θ, w, th], 
     overlapSquare[a, b, θ] && 0 <= θ < Pi/2 && 0 <= a <= b}, {a, b, θ},
     PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxIterations -> 10,
     StepMonitor :> PrintTemporary["{a,b,θ,f} = ", {a,b,θ,overlap[a,b,θ,w,th]}]], 600000000]

Off[BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl];
minArea[1.0, 0.3]
```

Comment: Have you reported this to Wolfram Technical Support?

Comment: No I have not! I'll do so and see what they say.

Comment: You should definitely do that sooner than later when you encounter something like this that could be a possible bug. At the very least to report it, and they may possibly have a workaround for you!